# Playing Audio Data retrieved From Google Text to Speech Api

Tags: ios, swift, networking, audio, avfoundation

## Problem

I am using Google Text to Speech API to get the audio data for a given text. My issue is that audio plays but you cannot understand it at all; it is definitely the wrong audio. It sounds like a bunch of random noises. Maybe I am decoding the data wrong?

Can anyone help me get the correct audio and play it.

## My Code

### Codable Structs for JSON

```
struct TextToSpeechBody: Codable {
    
    var input: SynthesisInput
    var voice: VoiceSelectionParams
    var audioConfig: AudioConfig
    
}

struct SynthesisInput: Codable {
    
    var text: String
    
}

struct VoiceSelectionParams: Codable {
    
    var languageCode: String
    var name: String
    var ssmlGender: String
    
}

struct AudioConfig: Codable {
    
    var audioEncoding: String
    
}

struct ResponseBody: Codable {
    
    var audioContent: String
    
}
```

### Text To Speech Manager Class

The `playAudio(of text: String)` takes in as the text that we want speech for. I am using "Hello, what's up dude!".

It passes the text parameter to the `fetchAudio(from text: String, completion: @escaping (_ audioData: Data) -> Void)` function which handles all the networking.

```
class TextToSpeechManager: NSObject {
    
    //MARK: - Variables
    static let shared = TextToSpeechManager()
    
    private let baseURL = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=MYAPIKEY"
    private let httpMethod = "POST"
    private let languageCode = "en-US"
    private let maleVoice = "en-US-WaveNet-I"
    private let femaleVoice = "en-US-WaveNet-H"
    private let male = "MALE"
    private let female = "FEMALE"
    private let audioEncoding = "MP3"
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    var avPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    //MARK: - INIT
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func fetchAudio(from text: String, completion: @escaping (_ audioData: Data) -> Void) {
        
        // Initialize URL
        guard let url = URL(string: baseURL) else {
            print("Unable to form url")
            return
        }
        
        // Setup Request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = httpMethod
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        
        // Encode http Body
        let synthesisInput = SynthesisInput(text: text)
        let voiceParams = VoiceSelectionParams(languageCode: languageCode, name: maleVoice, ssmlGender: male)
        let audioConfig = AudioConfig(audioEncoding: audioEncoding)
        let body = TextToSpeechBody(input: synthesisInput, voice: voiceParams, audioConfig: audioConfig)
        
        guard let encodedBody = try? encoder.encode(body) else {
            print("Error Encoding Body")
            return
        }
        
        request.httpBody = encodedBody
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is nil")
                return
            }
            
            print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
            
            guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data) else {
                print("Unable to decode data")
                return
            }
            
            guard let audioData = Data(base64Encoded: response.audioContent) else {
                print("Unable to get audio data")
                return
            }
            
            completion(audioData)
            
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func playAudio(of text: String) {
        
        fetchAudio(from: text) { (audioData) in
           
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              do {
                self.avPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
                self.avPlayer?.play()
              } catch let error {
                print("Error occurred while playing audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
              }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

### Calling the Function

```
TextToSpeechManager.shared.playAudio(of: "Hello, what's up dude!")
```

### Google Documentation

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#AudioEncoding

This documentation describes the REST API and shows what the network request and response look like.

At the bottom of this website you can test out the API by filling in the request fields and it will show you the request output. I have the same output in my program as they do in there test GUI. This is why I'm thinking that I am either feeding the wrong type of data into the avPlayer or I did something wrong with respect to playing the audio.

Thanks for all your help!

### **Edit**

### Solution

I was able to find an example posted on Medium of a project that works. Here is the link to this project: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-integrate-google-cloud-text-to-speech-api-into-your-ios-app-140ab7be42ae

Based on his project I used a semaphore to make the request synchronous and it worked. **I am not sure I fully understand why so if anyone can explain I would love to hear. It is for this reason I haven't posted it as a solution yet because I would like to understand it before posting the solution**

#### Code that works

```
    func fetchAudio(from text: String, completion: @escaping (_ audioData: Data) -> Void) {
        
        var result = Data()
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
            // Initialize URL
            guard let url = URL(string: self.baseURL) else {
                print("Unable to form url")
                return
            }
            
            // Setup Request
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = self.httpMethod
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            
            
            // Encode http Body
            let synthesisInput = SynthesisInput(text: text)
            let voiceParams = VoiceSelectionParams(languageCode: self.languageCode, name: self.maleVoice, ssmlGender: self.male)
            let audioConfig = AudioConfig(audioEncoding: self.audioEncoding)
            let body = TextToSpeechBody(input: synthesisInput, voice: voiceParams, audioConfig: audioConfig)
            
            guard let encodedBody = try? self.encoder.encode(body) else {
                print("Error Encoding Body")
                return
            }
            
            request.httpBody = encodedBody
            
            // Using semaphore to make request synchronous
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Data is nil")
                    return
                }
                
                // print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
                
                guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data) else {
                    print("Unable to decode data")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let audioData = Data(base64Encoded: response.audioContent) else {
                    print("Unable to get audio data")
                    return
                }
                
                result  = audioData
                
                semaphore.signal()
                
            }
            task.resume()
            _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
            
           completion(result)
        }
                
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reasons why you don't want to use the `AVSpeechUtterance` class?

Comment: Is AVSpeechUtterance apples text to speech class? If so I have heard that the quality of speech is not as good as the google API. Have you used it?